# Is there any plan for creating badges for seriously downvoted questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, badges

When I use Meta Stack Overflow to ask and answer questions, I earn badges. I think it is a reward. So, is there also any plan for punishment? Is there any plan for creating new badges for seriously downvoted questions and answers?

Comment: I personally think that rep should be able to go negative.

Comment: I think some people would go about collecting all the bad badges they could find.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle That wouldn't allow you to recover from an initial mistake very well.

Comment: I think the community is expert on the subject of discouraging newcomers from making mistakes. You get edited, critisized and closed, sometimes rather tersely. Your reputation starts falling. I really think we've got this one covered.

Comment: I did enjoy the irony, however.

Comment: @AndrewC I'm semi-joking, I understand the reasons why we don't allow this and they are great reasons. Just can't help but wish sometimes :)

Comment: I don't think we should have "punishment" badges. It would spoil the atmosphere.

Comment: "So, is there also any plan for punishment?" I have personally tracked down and scourged multiple stackexchange site users whose questions have offended my exacting standards of etiquette, grammar, and technical prowess. However, I recognize that such a system- while perfect- is difficult to implement at a large scale. I am also aware that, unfortunately, scourging is not always afforded the protected legal status it enjoys in the United States.

Answer (score 13):

We generally avoid creating badges that would encourage a *negative* behaviour such as posting a question that will get heavily downvoted.

So at the moment there are no plans to create a badge for having a post of yours downvoted a lot.

But, there is a badge for removing a downvoted post of your own: [Peer Pressure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/36/peer-pressure).